# shell command to achieve SCP task in Cloudbees

Tags: shell, command, scp, cloudbees

In our project, there is one step in Cloudbees to obtain SCP task. But the SCP plugin in the Cloudbees is disabled and we don't have access to enable the plugins. How to achieve the same with the help of shell? What shell command has to be used for SCP task where we provide the details like

- Host Name
- Username and password
- Local Directory path
- What items to be copied from Local Path to remote
- Port number

Comment: What kind of tasks are you talking about, you need to provide more details. But I guess scp (secure copy) is just used to copy files remotly?

Comment: Yes..as SCP is used for copying files remotely, we are doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

scp is used this way to remotly copy files:

```
scp -P 21 "username@host_name:/home/example_user/local.file" /home/remotecopy.file
```

For password you will have to use sshpass or expect (expect is dirty)